# Calculate age from birthday date and display inputs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, forms

I'm trying to store a form into a database using Laravel 8.

**Form**

```
<form id="castingform" method="post" action="castings"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id"/>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="casting_name">Nom</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_name" 
                   name="casting_name" placeholder="Nom">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="casting_name">Prénom</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_prenom" 
                   name="casting_prenom" placeholder="Prenom">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="casting_cin">CIN</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_cin" 
                   name="casting_cin" placeholder="Cin">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="casting_date_naissance">Date de naissance</label>
            <div class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_date_naissance" 
                       name="casting_date_naissance">
                <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon">
                    <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="casting_lieu_naissance">Lieu de naissance</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_lieu_naissance" 
                   name="casting_lieu_naissance"
                   placeholder="Lieu de naissance">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor-container" hidden>
        <label for="guarantor">Nom et prénom du représentatnt légal </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guarantor" name="guarantor" 
               placeholder="Représentant">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 
        js-guarantor_identification_number-container" hidden>
        <label for="guarantor_identification_number">
            CIN du représentatnt légal
        </label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="guarantor_identification_number"
               name="guarantor_identification_number" placeholder="CINE">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor_lien-container" hidden>
        <label for="guarantor_identification_number">Lien</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_lien" name="casting_lien" 
               placeholder="Lien">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" align="center">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id"/>
        <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" 
            class="btn btn-warning" 
               value="ADD"/>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-6">
        <span id="form_result"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want it so that when I enter the birthday date, to calculate the age directly and, if the age is less than 18, display the hidden inputs. For example, I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
var dateinput = document.getElementById('casting_date_naissance');
var guarantorContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor-container');
var guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor_identification_number-container');
var guarantorLienContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor_lien-container');
var dob = new Date(dateinput);
dob.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    var a = moment($(this).val(), "MM/DD/YYYY").month(0).from(moment().month(0))
    if (+a < 18) {
        guarantorContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
        guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
        guarantorLienContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
    } else {
        guarantorContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
        guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
        guarantorLienContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
    }
});
```

I get the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: dob.addEventListener is not a function
> at HTMLDocument. (castingss:1078)
> at fire (jquery.js:1037)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:1148)
> at Function.ready (jquery.js:433)
> at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:103)

If you have any ideas, please help me.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Why don't you use `<input type="date" />` for a date input?

Comment: @shaedrich Now I'm using <input type="date" /> , the event fires ,but it seems like it doesn't verify if the age is less or greater than 18

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this even related to AJAX or PHP? You haven't shared any code related to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed two things:

1. `new Date()` constructor needs a date string, not an `<input />` HTML element
2. `addEventListener()` has to be applied to the `<input />` HTML element, not the instance of `new Date()`
3. I don't know if you're using jQuery but since you're using vanilla JS for selecting all the elements on top, I changed `$(this).val()` to `evt.target.value`. If you're using jQuery just ignore this one.
4. Your `moment($(this).val(), "MM/DD/YYYY").month(0).from(moment().month(0))` returned a string ('x years ago') that couldn't be parsed to number so it returned `NaN`.

```js
var dateinput = document.getElementById('casting_date_naissance');
var guarantorContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor-container');
var guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor_identification_number-container');
var guarantorLienContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor_lien-container');
var dob = new Date(dateinput.value);
dateinput.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
    var a = moment().diff(moment(evt.target.value, "MM/DD/YYYY"), 'years');
   if (a < 18) {
      guarantorContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
      guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
      guarantorLienContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
    } else {
      guarantorContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
      guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
        guarantorLienContainer.setAttribute('hidden',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , but now I get any error and the hidden input doesn't diplay

Comment: So you don't get any error message. Does the change event fire?

Comment: No , doesn't fire

Comment: It's because the console says: "TypeError: guarantorLienContainer is null" - or that's at least what it tells m

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: I can't find an element with class `'.js-guarantor_lien-container'` in your HTML and JavaScript can't either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233623/discussion-between-melissa-maya-and-shaedrich).

Answer (score -1):

The following is my attempt on putting together what needs to be done:

```js
const guarantor=document.querySelectorAll("div[class*=guarantor]");
document.getElementById("casting_date_naissance").addEventListener("input",ev=>{
 let adult=new Date(ev.target.value);
 adult = new Date()>adult.setFullYear(adult.getFullYear()+18);
 guarantor.forEach(g=>g.classList.toggle("hidden",adult));
})
```

```css
.hidden { display:none }
```

```html
<form id="castingform" method="post" action="castingss" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id" />
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="casting_name">Nom</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_name" name="casting_name" placeholder="Nom">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="casting_name">Prénom</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_prenom" name="casting_prenom" placeholder="Prenom">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="casting_cin">CIN</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_cin" name="casting_cin" placeholder="Cin">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="casting_date_naissance">Date de naissance</label>
            <div class="input-group date">

                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="casting_date_naissance" name="casting_date_naissance">
                <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon">
                    <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="casting_lieu_naissance">Lieu de naissance</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_lieu_naissance" name="casting_lieu_naissance"
                placeholder="Lieu de naissance">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor-container">
        <label for="guarantor">Nom et prénom du représentatnt légal </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guarantor" name="guarantor" placeholder="Représentant">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor_identification_number-container">
        <label for="guarantor_identification_number">CIN du représentatnt légal</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="guarantor_identification_number"
            name="guarantor_identification_number" placeholder="CINE">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor_lien-container">
        <label for="guarantor_identification_number">Lien</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_lien" name="casting_lien" placeholder="Lien">

    </div>


    <div class="form-group" align="center">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
        <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-warning" value="ADD" />
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-6">
        <span id="form_result"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

The line

```
adult = new Date()>adult.setFullYear(adult.getFullYear()+18);
```

determines whether the candidate is to be treated as an adult or not (boolean value). `adult` first contains the actual birthdate. From this date the actual 18th birthday is calculated which is then compared to the current date. In case the current date is greater than the calculated 18th birthday the candidate is considered "adult" and the visibility of the "guarantor" fields is changed accordingly.